# Memoir - change chapter header to native language

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I have been given a preamble prepared for writing in English, but I am writing in Danish. And at the top of page there is a small header, e.g.,

```
Chapter 8. My native chapter title
```

And I would like to change that to

```
Kapitel 8. My native chapter title
```

And by commenting out this line in my preamble this header disapears

```
\makeoddhead{my_page_style}{}{\small\sffamily\leftmark}{}
```

So, how do I modify this `\makeoddhead` to show chapter in my language?
N.B. I am using Memoir.

Comment: `\usepackage[danish]{babel}` in the preamble should do.

Comment: I tried that without success

Comment: Without seeing your preamble it's impossible to say more. You *should* use that line nonetheless, in order to ensure correct hyphenation for Danish. Say also `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Answer (score 2):

Danish `babel` *does* work, so would you please show us what you did in the first place. You should be using `\chaptername` to refer to the name (actually `\@chapapp` is better).

Plus there is no need for that test inside `\chaptermark`, this does the same thing

```
\createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
```

(from the default definition of `headings` in `memoir`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by modifying the line with the comment "THIS LINE!!" - I didn't show all the code - sorry for that. Was convinced it was the \makeoddhead line that should be modified

```
\makepagestyle{my_page_style}
\makeoddhead{my_page_style}{}{\small\sffamily\leftmark}{}
\makeoddfoot{my_page_style}{}{}{\small\sffamily\thepage}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\makeatletter
\makepsmarks{my_page_style}{%
  \renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{%
    \markboth{%
      \ifnum \value{secnumdepth} > 1
      \if@mainmatter % 
      \ Kapitel \thechapter. \ % THIS LINE!!
      \fi
      \fi
      ##1}{}}%
  \renewcommand\tocmark{\markboth{\contentsname}{\contentsname}}%
  \renewcommand\lofmark{\markboth{\listfigurename}{\listfigurename}}%
  \renewcommand\lotmark{\markboth{\listtablename}{\listtablename}}%
  \renewcommand\bibmark{\markboth{\bibname}{\bibname}}%
  \renewcommand\indexmark{\markboth{\indexname}{\indexname}}%
  \renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{##1}}%
  \renewcommand\subsectionmark[1]{\markright{##1}}%
  \renewcommand\subsubsectionmark[1]{\markright{##1}}%
}
```